# useSelector getting state multiple times

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm using react, redux, and redux toolkit (redux-thunk).
so I'm trying to get lists from the server and show it on the page.

i used dispatch and saved the response in redux and used useSelector to get lists in the response.

everything is working okay but here is the problem:
I only want to get state once , but it keeps showing state multiple times.
(screenshot here)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up98Z.png)

```
dispatch(getMainLists());
```

slice.js -> extra reducers

```
extraReducers: {
[getMainLists.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
  console.log("GET FULFILLED");
  console.log(action.payload);
  state.genreList = [...action.payload.genreList];
  state.latestList = [...action.payload.latestList];
  state.likeList = [...action.payload.likeList];
},
```

useSelector in Main component:

```
  const genreList = useSelector((state)=> state.Song.genreList, shallowEqual);
  const latestList = useSelector((state)=> state.Song.latestList, shallowEqual);
  const likeList = useSelector((state)=> state.Song.likeList,shallowEqual);
  console.log(genreList);
  console.log(likeList);
  console.log(latestList);
```

I used shallowEqual to fix this problem but it still isnt working right.

I tried this also:

```
const [genreList, latestList,likeList] = useSelector((state) => [
state.Song.genreList,
state.Song.latestList,
state.Song.likeList,
```

])

still not working.

Comment: Did you call dispatch inside a useEffect hook?

Comment: This isn't really something to worry about. How often the body of your function component gets invoked is up to react. Just make sure `getMainLists` is only dispatched when you expect it.

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka yes I callled dispatch inside a useEffect hook, because I need that list when a component is mounted. Is there another way???

Comment: @timotgl thank you for the advise. I never thought this would be a problem, but it gets  lists multiple times and shows the lists multiple times on the view. ( for example, i want to show the photos in the lists. I would map the list and do something like this: likeList.map{(song,index) ... .... img src={song.photo}  ... is there are 3 items in likeList, only 3 photos should appear, but 6 would pop up.

Comment: Maybe share your `useEffect` code.